# Using Barcode Detection API in chrome is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, barcode

I'm trying to implement a barcode scanner using camera for my web app. it should mostly detect code 39 barcodes that contains some id. I'm using asp.net core razor pages to build my web app.
using barcode detection Api in chrome android and a code like below I was able to read the barcodes without any problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        video {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <video></video>
    <script>
        const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');

        function scan(detector) {
            detector.detect(videoElement)
                .then(console.log)
                .catch(console.error);
        }

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
            audio: false,
            video: {
                facingMode: "environment",
                zoom: 200
            }
        }).then((stream) => {
            videoElement.srcObject = stream;
            videoElement.play();
            let detector = new BarcodeDetector({ formats: ['code_39'] });
            setInterval(scan, 300, detector);
        }, console.error)
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

but testing on another phone it fails to detect any barcode. what could be the problem?

My phone's chrome version is 104 and the other phone is 110. both phones support all the necessary Apis like Barcode Detection API and Media Capture and Streams API.

Thinking the problem might be with the Barcode Detector I used other libraries like:

- [html5-qrcode](https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode)
- [ZXing wasm](https://github.com/Sec-ant/barcode-detector)

but still didn't get any results.

Also thinking that somehow camera quality is causing problem I used [a barcode generator](https://barcode.tec-it.com/en/Code39?data=ABC-1234) to generate a barcode and used the image and it still didn't detect any thing.

I also tried to use web workers to do the decoding in case main thread is to busy and in the end, there were no difference.

Using [scandit barcode scanner](https://websdk.demos.scandit.com/) or [dynamsoft barcode scanner](https://demo.dynamsoft.com/barcode-reader-js/) I was able to detect barcodes perfectly.
After testing on other devices, some devices have no problem detecting and some other don't detect anything. I have no idea what could be the reason for this inconsistent behavior.

What do you think might be the reason? and what solutions do you suggest?

**Edit:**
these are the result of running the same code two different phones

[detect may even take 2 seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaMmq.png)
[detect takes a reasonable amount of time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPhuX.png)

Comment: Is there a question or are you reporting an issue with a particular device?

Comment: i have a question. I tried to solve anything i could think might be causing my problem, and nothing seems to work.

Comment: The code works on one unnamed device with Chrome that is 9 versions behind current - and does not work on another unnamed device with chrome 15 versions behind current .... so, either update Chrome on unnamed device 2, or perhaps unnamed device 2 has a really bad camera, neither of which we can tell you, you have to actually test

Comment: ^^^ I may have misunderstood which phone works and which doesn't though ...

Comment: I tested my codes on only four devices, two of them had no problem, but the other two were either very slow (up to minutes) to decode the barcode or didn't detect anything at all. I added the chrome version part because I thought there might be a bug in version 110 that I don't know about. although if there is any problem with BarcodeDetector the other libraries should not have worked, but they did.

Comment: about the camera having poor quality, not only i couldn't detect the barcode even when using an image instead of frames coming from the camera, using demos of the two prosperity software i mentioned (scandit and dynamsoft), they did detect and decode the barcode without any problem, so how can it be because of camera?

Comment: am i missing some configuration for the camera? then why can't i decode the computer generated barcode image. is there a problem with Barcode Detection API? then why other libraries can't detect anything either. is there somehow a problem with the devices? then why dynamsoft barcode scanner works so good? what do you think i'm missing here? how should i approach this problem? (in earlier comment i meant using other libraries should have worked, but they didn't)

Comment: I thought your code works in one device - therefore your code is fine and you know how to do all those things

Comment: Have you tried to read barcodes from static images instead of video stream?

Comment: yes, yet detect takes way to long and has to result.

Comment: and has no result